# Customer colour in IIF expression -SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a column in our `SSRS` report which shows the date value based on `expression.`

We used below `expression`.

```
="Actual Max Date: " + (IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "dataset1")),"N/A",First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "dataset2")))
```

the logic is as below,

IF the date is NULL then `"N/A"` is displayed , else actual date is displayed. Here my requirement is to show the string `"N/A"` in red colour. How to achieve it in `SSRS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the same condition that determines the **N/A** to determine the color:

```
=IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "dataset1")), "Red", "DimGray")
```

Place the expression in the **Color** property of the text box - it's on the **FILL** tab if using the popup property box.

To color only part of the text in the textbox, you would need to use HTML formatting in the expression.

```
="<b>Actual Max Date: </b><font color='" 
& IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "dataset1")), "Red", "Black") & "'>" 
& IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "dataset1")), "N/A", First(Fields!ActualMaxDate.Value, "DataSet1"))
& "</font>"
```

Make sure you set the **Markup Type** of the ***Placeholder Property*** to **HTML**.

Comment: no friend. it will change the colour of entire text box. i want colour change only in the string "N/A"

Comment: Ah - I missed that part. You would need to use HTML formatting. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I just removed an extra bracket on 2nd IIF expression. Could you tell me what is the use of & operator in this expression?

Comment: The **&** concatenates text like the plus sign. They are mostly interchangeable though I think there was some issue I had years ago due to using a + instead of &. I think the plus assumes numeric but then reverts to text. I wonder if there's a performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the textbox => Properties => BackgroundColor =>

Fill in your expression like

```
=IIF("N/A"="N/A","Red","Blue")
```

Comment: Thanks. but it changes the colour of entire textbox . i need to change colour of the string "n/a" only

Comment: Also if  "N/A" = "N/A"  then condition will be always true is it?

Comment: that's just an example, you may use the value you want

Comment: if you want change colour for the String, just paste your expression in 'Color'

Comment: textbox properties = > font  => Color